# Catch onTouch event by parent, handle it and pass to children

Tags: android, android-layout, click, touch, touch-event

I tried to understand how Android handle touch event and got a little bit confused. From what I understand touch event are send to the root view and pass down to the children.
I have a `FrameLayout` that is a container for `Fragment`.
First fragment view is a `ScrollView`, second one is some kind of `Gallery` (HorizontalListView) and the last one is also `FrameLayout`. Only one fragment in the layout each time.
What I want to do is to identify user swipes on the screen, for the app use. I want to count the swipes and do something after some number of swipes.

I tried to put a `OnTouchListener` on the top `FrameLayout` but it doesn't get called when the child is the `ScrollView` or the `Gallery`. I tried to return `false` and also `true` in the end of `onTouch`, but I get same result - it's never being called.

How can I do it?
I just want to "transparently" handle the touch events and passing them on like I didn't even touch them.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My understanding is that it actually goes the other direction.  The Child views get their event triggered first (sort of). The root view get's it's `dispatchTouchEvent()` called, which propagates the event down to the children's `onTouchEvent()`, and then, depending on whether they return true or false, the parent's `onTouchEvent()` is called.

The normal solution for intercepting things like this is to override `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` in one's activity like so:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev) {
  // Do your calcluations
  return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

The documentation for this one is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).  Note that you can also override that method in any `ViewGroup` (such as a `FrameLayout`, etc)

Comment: It worked! I extended `FrameLayout`, overrode the method you've mentioned, and sent the `MotionEvent` to a `GestureDetector`. All this subject is a little confusing. Thanks!

Comment: @Elad92 like you mentioned can you help me to change this 2d scroll code?  https://gist.github.com/LOG-TAG/0505eedccef9e00821da didn't getting  how to  _send the MotionEvent to a GestureDetector_

Comment: so perhaps  you would not use `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)`  in the parent